# how to use html5 with django forms?

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, django-forms

I want to use this snippet

```
# extra.py in yourproject/app/

from django.db.models import FileField
from django.forms import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(FileField):
    """
    Same as FileField, but you can specify:
        * content_types - list containing allowed content_types. Example: ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg']
        * max_upload_size - a number indicating the maximum file size allowed for upload.
            2.5MB - 2621440
            5MB - 5242880
            10MB - 10485760
            20MB - 20971520
            50MB - 5242880
            100MB 104857600
            250MB - 214958080
            500MB - 429916160
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_types = kwargs.pop("content_types")
        self.max_upload_size = kwargs.pop("max_upload_size")

        super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

        file = data.file
        content_type = file.content_type

        if content_type in self.content_types:
            if file._size > self.max_upload_size:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(self.max_upload_size), filesizeformat(file._size)))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Filetype not supported.'))

        return data
```

with this snippet

```
// fileInput is a HTMLInputElement: <input type="file" multiple id="myfileinput">
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");
// files is a FileList object (simliar to NodeList)
var files = fileInput.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    alert(files[i].name + " has a size of " + files[i].size + " Bytes");
}
```

so i can check the size of a file using html5, how to combine these 2 snippets into 1? i also found a java snippet which upload the video and check the size but i can't find any doc on how to implement it. I can't use javascript coz i can't trust the client

Comment: Please shorten your question so it's easily readable, and clearly as one specific thing. Remove all the stuff that isn't relevant like whatever those quotes are.

Comment: @agf the response that mikko gave made me so angry, and when i angry i talk too much to express my anger, i edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

Create a Widget for this field based on django's file input widget. Add JS from second snippet to the output of that widget. And pass value of max_upload_size from field to the widget on creation on rendering.